# LT spice: change amplitude of a voltage source over time in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, amplitude

I would like to have a sinusoidal voltage source that varies over time, for example;
 for time duration 1msec  : 3v 13.56MHz
for time duration 2msec  : 10v 13.56MHz

please help.

i studied Help for the behavioral voltage source, but i cant write the code.
because i need a pulse waveform to write the code.

and ideas?

Comment: If you meant I *would like to* have a sinusoidal voltage source, please change your post accordingly. If not, could you please rephrase your request? Next, do you mean the source should change on time stamps 1msec, 2 msec etc? Or at time stamp 1msec, the source should be 10v 13.56 MHz for 2 msec, so from time stamp 1msec to time stamp 3msec? (I assume you want Hertz instead of Henrey?)

Comment: Anyway: use a Arbitrary behavioral voltage source and start with changing the Value to "V=time", check the output. Open the help file and find how to program it to your needs. We're happy to advise on your result.

Comment: What’s 13.56MH? 13 megahenries?

Comment: @winny I think it's not hard to know OP intentions, it is likely MHz, like I commented earlier.

Comment: yes, you are right! i mean 13.56 Mhz
and about time... i mean the time duration.



 I want to edit my question, but i dont know how

Comment: i would like to have a sinusoidal  voltage source to be with 3volt for time duration 1msec, and 10volt for time duration 2 msec , and the frequency is 13.56 Mhz (ISM band)

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: @huisman thanks for introducing the BV, i studied help, but i cant write the code to generate such signal... i think i need pulse signal to generate it. could you please help me?

Comment: @atizs  i cant write the code for behavioral voltage source, to generate such signal. can you please help me?

Comment: @Huisman If I have to guess/OP can’t spend the effort to write a clear question, it’s VTC as unclear from me. It’s not that hard.

Comment: @winny It's indeed no effort/easier to VTC. I prefer pushing OP's to improve their questions. I agree the OP could have shown more effort. But why not comment *that* plainly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a pulsing source makes it easier:

[image]

I had to adjust the Maximum Timestep in order to see some decent output. I chose about 10 points to represent a sign (hence 1 / 150 MHz), maybe 2 will do as well.
If you zoom in enough, you might see the 13.56 MHz waveform :-)

Considering the required timestep, I'm actually wondering if you really want to do this.

Comment: thanks for your help dear huisman